# What machine learning paradigm / algorithm can I use to select from a pool of possible choices?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I have a large question bank and students. The goal is to select questions for an exam for a student.

Questions have various properties:

- Grade Level
- Subjects (could be multiple: fractions, word problems, addition)
- How other students did on this question (percent right, wrong, etc)
- Has the student seen this question before or those like it?

So I want to choose questions for a student based on how the student is doing. My feedback for whether or not it's a "good" exam is the following:

- Human feedback. A person can review the exam and reject certain questions for qualitative reasons
- How the student does on the exam? If they got 100% right, that's bad. If they got 20% right, that's bad. We want to target 75%
- Qualitative feedback on the exam as a whole from the teacher

I feel that a neural network is a possible solution here, but I'm not sure how. Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: (1) So you are targeting equal performance on all students, despite their potential / prep. What kind of educational system is that? (2) This question is lacking so much information that it cannot be answered (even if one would tackle it ignoring the meaning of this scenario) (3) (a bit offensive, but sometimes that is my reaction to questions like these: ) why is everyone, clearly missing ML-knowledge always crying for NNs? It's not a silver-bullet. And in the hands of unexperienced people doing way less than much more simple approaches. Especially in highly "model-based" tasks like this!

Comment: (1) it's not QUITE that simple - the idea is we want to introduce 30% `new concepts` and 70% `things they're good at`. Eventually, that'll be made dynamic as well. (2) I'm happy to provide more info (3) NN is my best guess - I'm happy to be told I'm wrong.

Comment: (1) Well, that's the first sign of beeing way too broad in your description. (2) So you are tuning exams for each single student? Based on some information & past behaviour? I'm just curious here, because that would be probably illegal in my country (in most setups)!

Comment: Yes - we want to tune exams for each student based on their past behavior (across different skills, performance, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether neural networks are the *best* way to go here. They could be, but I thought almost instantly of something else.

Given the information in your question, you might want to check a statistic approach here, with some techniques like [PCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) or more broadly [multivariate analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_statistics).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly you would have to learn whether the relation between a question and a student is "good" or "bad"? This would give you a binary classification problem, where the input is a feature vector combining both the question's features as well as that of the student?

You can always throw this in a network and see how it does, I'm guessing that you don't have too many questions and students, but as you're classifying pairs your datasize does increase, which is nice.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest probabilistic modeling, since you have some noise on your real data introduced by the human evaluation. Two annotator would not for sure give the same "qualitative feedback" about the same exam.

It's best to have a model that takes account of uncertainties; Bayesian approach ! If you have little knowledge about this area, I point you to [Bishop - Pattern recognition book - freely available online](http://users.isr.ist.utl.pt/~wurmd/Livros/school/Bishop%20-%20Pattern%20Recognition%20And%20Machine%20Learning%20-%20Springer%20%202006.pdf) and you can use library like [mc-stan lib](http://mc-stan.org/) or [edward-lib](http://edwardlib.org/tutorials/). There's also a course about probabilistic modeling on [coursera](https://www.coursera.org/), where in the first chapters they treat an example very close to your use case.

One more comment about your suggestion using NN: since you don't have a lot of features (6 as you have mentioned), NN will easily overfit unless you have millions of data points.. This is slightly easy problem in terms of model complexity and you don't need hidden layers to accomplish a good result.

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

Try also looking over Ranking Algorithms. You can train it for combination (student, question) and point this kind of combinations or generate an ordered function.

I don't have much experience with it but may be worth trying it.